# Заполнение таблицы в Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Начинаю изучать ApachePOI. Столкнулась с проблемой заполнения таблицы.
Код, приведенный ниже, создает две страницы, названия рядов и элементы, такая себе "окантовка" таблицы в файле xls. 
данные на странице Two такие же.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  public class Excel {
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet;
    public void Excel() throws Exception {
 ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =1;i<=30;i++) {
            num.add(i);
        }
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("One");
        strings.add("Two");
        ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add(1);
        elements.add(2);
        elements.add(3);
        elements.add(4);
        elements.add(5);
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("Name1");
        names.add("Name2");
        names.add("Name3");

              for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {//названия страниц
            sheet = wb.createSheet(strings.get(i));
            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Count of elements");

            for (int cellCounter = 1; cellCounter <= elements.size(); cellCounter++) {
                    row.createCell(cellCounter).setCellValue(elements.get(cellCounter - 1));
                }
                   for (int rowCounter = 1; rowCounter <= names.size(); rowCounter++) {
                sheet.createRow(rowCounter).createCell(0).setCellValue(names.get(rowCounter-1));
                  for(int j=0; j<=num.size(); j++){
                      int cellIndex=1;
                      sheet.createRow(rowCounter).createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(j);
                  }

                sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
                       }
                   }
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Home/Desktop/table.xls");
                wb.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
            }
        }
```

теперь вопрос:допустим, есть массив чисел от 1 до 30. и эти числа нужно разместить, что бы получилось так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 как это сделать? 
У меня если что-то и получается, то пропадает часть уже созданной таблицы. Но целую таблицу не знаю как сделать.

Comment: Тут некоторые проблемы с кодом. 1. Избавься от использования `j` и `x`, вместо них используй уже имеющиеся `cellCounter` и `rowConter`, иначе код очень запутан. 2. Я не вижу вложенного цикла внутри цикла c `x`, который бы собственно и заполнял значения от 1 до 15 и от 16 до 30.

Comment: @Темкатоже Первое исправила, если я правильно Вас поняла. А на счет второго: в том то и проблема. Я не знаю как прописать этот цикл вложенный. Мою попытку я тоже добавила. Но я знаю что это не правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void create() throws Exception {
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet;
    int num = 1;
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("One");
    strings.add("Two");
    ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    elements.add(1);
    elements.add(2);
    elements.add(3);
    elements.add(4);
    elements.add(5);
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("Name1");
    names.add("Name2");
    names.add("Name3");

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {//названия страниц
        sheet = wb.createSheet(strings.get(i));

        int rowCounter = 0;
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Count of elements");

        for (int cellCounter = 1; cellCounter <= elements.size(); cellCounter++) {
            row.createCell(cellCounter).setCellValue(elements.get(cellCounter - 1));
        }
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(rowCounter);
        rowCounter++;
        for (; rowCounter <= names.size(); rowCounter++) {
            Row rt = sheet.createRow(rowCounter); //Создаем строку только ОДИН раз
            rt.createCell(0).setCellValue(names.get(rowCounter - 1));
            for (int cellIndex = 1; cellIndex <= 5; cellIndex++) {
                rt.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(num);
                num++;
            }

        }
    }

    File file = File.createTempFile("questions787162", ".xlsx");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        wb.write(fos);
    }
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

}
```

Кстати, советую не держать столько логики в конструкторе.

Comment: вроде понятно, но мне надо заполнять массив именно по колонкам, а не по рядам

Comment: @alexanaw Excel оперирует иерархией `ряд->колонка`, поэтому заполнение идёт в таком порядке

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за интересный пример, пришлось таки и мне разбираться, по милости Божьей, с данным вопросом,
заодно усовершенствовал код товарища @Темка тоже таким образом, чтобы он считал именно так, как Вам хотелось, - то есть, увеличивая num по столбцам, а не по рядкам:))

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exelizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            create();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void create() throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet;
        int num;  //здесь удалил неиспользуемую инициализацию
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("One");
        strings.add("Two");
        ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add(1);
        elements.add(2);
        elements.add(3);
        elements.add(4);
        elements.add(5);
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("Name1");
        names.add("Name2");
        names.add("Name3");

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
            sheet = wb.createSheet(strings.get(i));

            int rowCounter = 0;
            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Count of elements");

            for (int cellCounter = 1; cellCounter <= elements.size(); cellCounter++) {
                row.createCell(cellCounter).setCellValue(elements.get(cellCounter - 1));
            }
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(rowCounter);
            rowCounter++;
            for (; rowCounter <= names.size(); rowCounter++) {
                num = rowCounter + i*15; //здесь, собственно, инициализировал динамически
                Row rt = sheet.createRow(rowCounter);
                rt.createCell(0).setCellValue(names.get(rowCounter - 1));
                for (int cellIndex = 1; cellIndex <= 5; cellIndex++) {
                    rt.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(num);
                    num+=3; //здесь поменял сообразно количеству рядков
                }

            }
        }

        File file = File.createTempFile("questions787162", ".xlsx");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            wb.write(fos);
        }
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }
}
```